# Apache Proxy configuration

Tags: apache, proxy, mod-proxy

I'd like to setup an Apache server proxy environment to achieve this: whatever `[URL]` you type in the browser, the Apache server "proxies" this  to `http://mydistantserver.com/[URL encoded]`.

Example: in the brower, I type `http://amazon.com` => goes to local Apache proxy, which *internally* changes it to `http://mydistantserver.com/amazon.com` then proxies it (=> calls `http://mydistantserver.com/amazon.com` and send the result back to the browser).

Is there a way to put ny rewriterule **before** it's used by the Apache server proxy module?

Oh by the way: my PC already uses a "global" proxy. So I'd like Apache proxy to configure its "workers" to use this "global" proxy otherwise they wont be able to make the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to put ny rewriterule before it's used by the Apache server proxy module?

No, Apache does not work that way.